# Create SVG image from json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, svg

I have this following code:

[at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dustcomposer/bapwnhy0/)

```
var cresc_path = '<path class="dyna_line" id="dyna_line" d="M ' + 0 + ' ' + 0 + ' L ' + 50 + ' ' + 25 + ' M ' + 0 + ' ' + 50 + ' L ' + 50 + ' ' + 25 + '" style="stroke-width: 1; stroke: red; fill:none;" />';

var dl = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
dl.setAttribute('class', 'dyHolder');
dl.setAttribute('id', 'dyHolder');
dl.setAttribute('style', 'border:1px solid red');
dl.setAttribute('width', '50');
dl.setAttribute('height', '50');
dl.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
dl.innerHTML = cresc_path;

document.getElementById('a').appendChild(dl);

var str = '<svg class="dyHolder" id="dyHolder" style="border:1px solid red" width="50" height="50" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path class="dyna_line" id="dyna_line" d="M 0 0 L 50 25 M 0 50 L 50 25" style="stroke-width: 1; stroke: red; fill:none;"></path></svg>';

document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = str;
```

both *dl* and *str* does result a svg image in html page. but when I grab similar string (*str*) from json file, it appears as text on the html page:

json:

```
[
[
"24/11/2014 - 4:32", "blah", "blah blah", "blah blah blah"
],
[ 
"<svg class=\"dyHolder\" id=\"dyHolder\" style=\"1px solid red\" width=\"140\" height=\"10\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\"><path class=\"dyna_line\" id=\"dyna_line\" d=\"M 0 5 L 140 0 M 0 5 L 140 10\" style=\"stroke-width: 1; stroke: black; fill:none;\"></path></svg>", "", ""
]
]
```

result:

```
This is text Lorem Ipsum blah blah <svg class="dyHolder" id="dyHolder" style="border:1px solid red" width="50" height="50" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path class="dyna_line" id="dyna_line" d="M 0 0 L 50 25 M 0 50 L 50 25" style="stroke-width: 1; stroke: black; fill:none;"></path></svg>. Another text..
```

Q: can I get json string object above (the *str*) as svg image when inserted to html page?

Comment: There are probably escape characters in the json string. Dump it to console and check.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/a1wcdejf/

Comment: Hi, that was fast reply, thanks! The backslash is required as I got json error: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token d'.

Comment: @oriol, it works too with me, the error happen when I get the string from a json file.